# purpose of Salesforce Shield Encryption

Tags: shield-encryption

1. What is purpose of using salesforce shield encryption, when the encrypted fields are not being masked
   in Rest Calls, data load export files etc,
2. what benefits we get it from doing so.
   3)How would we verify if the encryption is working apart from destroying the key

Answer (score 1):

The reason has been explained as Platform Encryption has limitations, Shield was designed to be un-intrusive, and to ensure data is encrypted at rest in the event that a Salesforce server is ever breached your data remains safe.

Salesforce doesn't offer any Out-of-box options to mask data as we wanted to remove the masking feature released with v1 of encryption due to misuse of the product. You have two options, the first is a custom solution that you design to hide data via special characters, or second, a third-party app or solution that does the same such as the one linked below:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000ErAUSUA3

While I cannot speak to the validity of the third-party product offered above it looks to mask data for standard objects.

Salesforce has decoupled the masking feature from Platform Encryption, as this was never meant to be used for the purpose of masking or hiding data from Salesforce users through the UI. Instead, it was meant to store your data encrypted at REST within the database, should it be compromised. If you wish to hide data from specific groups of Salesforce users, then you must test this through your sandbox and utilize Field Level Security, along with page layouts to control this part. These are the current limitations that I have no further facts. If you have data you don’t want specific users to see, revisit their field-level security settings, record access settings, and object permissions. As mentioned in our considerations, please see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5

Again, the Salesforce Platform Encryption solution is about encrypting data at rest and the rest of the masking has to be tested and managed by your admin team through Field Level Security, alongside page layouts. A security solution as powerful as Shield Platform Encryption doesn't come without some tradeoffs. When your data is encrypted, some users may see limitations to some functionality, and a few features aren't available at all. Consider the impact on your users and your overall business solution as you design your encryption strategy.

Platform Encryption Resources to assist you in the process:

Shield Platform Encryption Implementation Guide

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf

Shield Platform Encryption Architecture White Paper

https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/Platform_Encryption_Architecture_White_Paper.pdf

Protect Your Salesforce Data with Shield Platform Encryption

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_overview.htm&type=0

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_masking.htm

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would just add that page layouts are not a security feature, just a formatting technique. FLS is the way to securely prevent data access by Users, while encryption defeats "hacker" access at other levels: physical access to servers, access to the database that underlies the force.com layer, access to the file system that underlies the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to emphasize the following points from the [introductory documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_overview.htm&type=5) and to clarify the meaning of some of the terms used:

> Shield Platform Encryption gives your data a whole new layer of security while preserving critical platform functionality. It enables you to encrypt sensitive data at rest, and not just when transmitted over a network, so your company can confidently comply with privacy policies, regulatory requirements, and contractual obligations for handling private data

Do not confuse the term "at rest" with "REST" (Representational state transfer). The term "at rest" means when the data is sat in the database. As is mentioned in the above quote, Shield ensures the data is encrypted, uniquely for your org, in the database; there are already other mechanisms for handling encyption of data "in flight", i.e. when being transported over the network, such as HTTPS and the use of TLS (Transport Layer Security).

There is an assumption that the data, from those fields for those objects for which you have enabled Shield, is not accessible in any way by third parties after it is read from the database and decrypted by the Salesforce Lightning Platform for use in Apex code or for sending over secured network transport to an integrated system or UI. Securing the in-memory data is handled entirely separately by the Salesforce multi-tenanting mechanisms.

The primary benefit of encrypting the data is against unauthorized access to the underlying database technology used in the Salesforce platform - someone gaining access could in principle get a dump of your data and access sensitive details. This benefit then allows implementers using the Salesforce platform to conform with regulatory requirements (laws) that require certain types of data to be stored securely (for example personally identifiable information such as contact names, postal and email addresses and phone numbers).

To verify that encryption is truly working would likely require corruption of your encryption key, though as with many of the Salesforce platform services recall that Salesforce submits its platform for external audit to gain accreditations and thus you can "trust" that it does work when enabled and applied.

The Setup UI (and metadata/tooling APIs) provides access to information that demonstrates which fields you have enabled encryption for. Additionally, you can see that the encryption is having effect by the fact that you can no longer perform SOQL queries that use LIKE or ORDER BY against the encrypted fields, for example.